# is there a non-file-based named mutex in boost

Tags: c++, boost, mutex

is there a non-file-based named mutex in boost? My problem is, that the file won't be deleted in case the process crashes. The file will even survive a reboot.

regards,
Tobias

Comment: Do you need to share the mutex between processes? (I suppose you do if you are asking about a *named* mutex, but better be clear). And are you using Windows or Unix (the as behaviour with what is created might be different)?

Comment: yes, I need to share between processes. Primary usage is on Win32, but a portable solution would be preferable, hence the question for a boost solution.

Answer (score 3):

For windows it is possible to use `boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::winapi_mutex_wrapper` since it is not file based

Comment: I created a ticket sine this one seems unofficial. See https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/12370

Answer (score 0):

> Boost.Interprocess offers the following mutex types:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_mutex.hpp>
```

> interprocess_mutex: A non-recursive, anonymous mutex that can be placed in shared memory or memory mapped files.

```
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_recursive_mutex.hpp>
```

> interprocess_recursive_mutex: A recursive, anonymous mutex that can be placed in shared memory or memory mapped files.

```
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_mutex.hpp>
```

> named_mutex: A non-recursive, named mutex.

```
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_recursive_mutex.hpp>
```

> named_recursive_mutex: A recursive, named mutex.

I suggest to use named mutex. See [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.mutexes)

Comment: the named_mutex (at least in default settings) creates a file. This is not what I want, hence my question.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I check the implementation in 1.46 branch (take a look at <boost/interprocess/sync/named_mutex.hpp>) - it creates file in shared memory.

Comment: May be `boost::thread::mutex` do the job. I've not used it though